# Can two terminal windows running on the same OS at the same time, communicate with one another?

Tags: linux, macos

I was wondering if it's possible to send a young message such as "hello world" from one terminal/cmd window to another terminal/cmd window - both running at the same time on the same operating system?

I'm using mac OSX and have access to a linux OS.

Comment: Your question is too vague. What is running in the "terminal window"? Just a shell? Do you just want a message to appear on the shell prompt? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Is it possible to have the message appear on the other shell prompt?

Comment: You can use `mesg`. Or talk over a named pipe.

Comment: Thank You, choroba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, go to the first terminal and type:

```
tty
```

and copy the output.

Then go in the second one and type:

```
echo Hello > CMD+V
```

But that is not very clever, choroba's `mesg` is more sensible.

Comment: Yesss! Thank You, Mark.